# Phone restarting over and over after rooting Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830i

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-ace, boot-loop, unrooting

I rooted my Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830i from the link given below-
http://theunlockr.com/2012/11/22/how-to-root-the-samsung-galaxy-ace-s5830/

However after rooting it, it is restarting again and again.
I unrooted it but still the same problem exists.

I even factory reset my Android phone. But still the phone restarts!

Comment: That very much looks like the rooting process messed up the `/system` partition (otherwise, the factory reset should have sorted things out). If that's the case, you might need to flash a fresh firmware (stock or custom -- the latter would need root again).

Comment: Strange I have the same here, it even reboots with stock firmware, I know how to flash.
But it Always starts after Play store is updated. It happens since the last update of playstore 2 weeks ago. If I reflash rebooting stops, if I open market and it updates. The Phone starts rebooting 3x per hour to 1 x per day. It is very unpredictable! You need to update the playstore, so I get this problem on stock firmware after opening playstore once.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bootloop (samsung logo looping), it is because you messed up the rooting procedure. I had this problem when I tried to root a relative's Ace.

Since you've tried factory reset and it doesn't work, enter recovery mode and do factory reset. (recovery mode: press and hold volume down + power button for 15 seconds, navigate up/down by volume button and power button to select). Reboot and see if it fixes the issue.

If it does not, there are two options: flash CWM from recovery (here's the [CWM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=952885&d=1332074949) zip file to flash from stock recovery), then reboot to CWM and install a custom ROM. This is what I did, as I wanted to load CM7 anyway.

If you want stock, download Odin, get stock firmware from [sammobile.com](http://sammobile.com) or [XDA forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) (look for Developmet section under your device specific forum) and flash it.

Comment: Thx..it did solve the problem but once I switched it off and started it again..it started rebooting again and again!Before switching it off, it did not had that rebooting problem.Is there any way out?

Comment: Describe what you did - factory reset, flashing custom ROM through CWM or stock ROM through Odin?

Comment: I flashed custom ROM through CWM.

Comment: Did you flash the custom ROM after doing a data wipe? If that doesn't fix it, you'll have to flash stock firmware through Odin. Be careful and make sure you pick the firmware specifically for your phone, else you'll brick your phone.