# Phone restarting again and again

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, boot-loop

I am having samsung galaxy ace GT-s5830i.
The phone is restarting again and again after installing a game from 4shared.com.please help me out.
Phone is rooted one.

Comment: Did you try to uninstall the game and/or unrooting?

Comment: Related: [LG Motion Keep Rebooting (Boot Loop) After Installing Beat Audio Installation](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38847/16575). One more hint: Hover your mouse over the `boot-loop` tag, and follow the '[info](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info)' link: Many of our tag wikis already contain general help, as in this case (always worth a look ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I had a similar problem with my Samsung Galaxy Nexus after downloading some apps I had developed without testing them on an emulator first (whops). Take a look at this question:[Phone restarting over and over after rooting Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830i](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36352/phone-restarting-over-and-over-after-rooting-samsung-galaxy-ace-s5830i). I know there is not an accepted answer but you might have some luck with it. I had to reset mine and that seem to do the trick but if not I would recommend the safe reboot described in the linked question. The actual problem is probably caused by an over load maybe of to much memory required for the graphics (as it was in my case). I would just be careful when downloading apps not from Google Play, especially any sort of game that uses a lot of ram and CPU. Hope this helps. Cheers.